# Error in emscripten when including glfw and opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, emscripten

I am using emscripten to compile my c++ game for the web. I am trying to use glfw3 and OpenGL for this as well.

However, when I include:

```
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
```

and:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

I get dozens of errors about things being redefined. I'll post an example of one below, but they're all very similar.

```
emsdk_portable/emscripten/master/system/include/GLES3/gl3.h:69:25: error: typedef
redefinition with different types ('khronos_ssize_t' (aka 'long') vs 'ptrdiff_t' (aka 'int'))
typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr;
```

EDIT: Why was this marked a duplicate of that question? Emscripten now comes bundled with glfw3 **and** OpenGL. I am pretty sure that glfw3 gets automatically linked too. When I try to include both of these libraries that come with Emscripten, I get the error I described above. Maybe I'm just being dumb here and my question actually is a duplicate of the other question. But if it is, could someone at least explain how? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Why did you mark my question as a duplicate? It's not..

Comment: I actually figured it out. It's not really related to the question that this was marked as a duplicate. I'm leaving this comment here in case anyone in the future has a similar problem. The solution is not to use "#include <GLES3/gl3.h>" at all, but instead, if you want to use OpenGL ES functions, you need to define "#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES3" and then "#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>" and opengl will get included with glfw. Also, when compiling your program, you need to include the compiler flag "-s USE_GLFW=3". I would leave this as an answer, but my question was wrongfully marked as a duplicate.